# Can I see all of my Comments in one place?

Tags: support

In order to help rectify the Comments Problem (as described elsewhere), I'd like to be able to see a full list of all my comments.

That way, I could go and delete the comments that didn't result in appropriate clarification and/or changes to questions or answers.

Is there a way to do this? For example, is there a link on my Profile page that would display such a list?

Comment: Done. I have deleted all my comments, other than the ones that the system locked.

Comment: I just want to point out, I don't think comments are inherently bad, but oftentimes here they end up in long discussions rather than "sticky notes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a link on your profile under activity, then filter by clicking "comments".

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7777/joe-strazzere?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7777/joe-strazzere?tab=activity

Comment: @enderland Thanks for the heads up, corrected the link to point to regular, not meta

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this to go back and delete all of my comments.

Comment: It would be nicer if there were a one-click way to delete all of my comments.